# Why is a ball that is moving in one direction and spinning in the opposite slowed down if the force of friction is tangential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

If a ball has linear and angular velocity such that there is a slip between the surface of the ball and ground, why does linear velocity of the center of the ball decrease if the force of friction is always tangential to the ball?

Comment: @BobD Not if there's a slip between the surface of the ball and ground.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is every particle of the ball, including those on the surface, have the same linear velocity wrt the as the COM. Regardless of slipping

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "spinning in the opposite direction". Say ball is moving to the right.  Then do you mean ball is rotating counter clockwise instead to clockwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does linear velocity of the center of the ball decrease if the
> force of friction is always tangential to the ball?

If I understand what you mean by "spinning in the opposite direction", the situation you described is shown in FIG 1 below. The figure assumes a perfectly horizontal surface and no external horizontal forces (rolling resistance, air drag, etc.) are acting on the ball other than kinetic friction.

Since it is given that the ball is sliding while rotating (i.e., $v_{com}\ne R\omega$) the sliding is opposed by the kinetic friction force $f_k$ which, as you say, acts tangentially on the surface of the ball as shown in FIG 1.

Although $f_k$ acts tangentially, any force can be moved to a different location as long as its line of action is the same, and the torque it causes at its original location is accounted for. In FIG 2 the friction force has been moved to act on the COM and a torque of $f_{k}R$ about the COM is added to account for the torque produced by $f_k$ at its actual location about the COM. So dynamically, FIG 2 is the equivalent of FIG 1.

The result is $f_{k}$ gives the COM a negative acceleration of $a_{com}=-f_{k}/M$ which slows the ball down) while at the same time, the clockwise torque of $f_{k}R$ acting opposite to the angular velocity $\omega$ causing the angular velocity (rotational motion) to slow down. The condition continues until $v_{com}=R\omega$ when friction becomes zero and pure rolling without slipping occurs.

The condition in Figure 1 is similar to the initial conditions of a "draw shot" in billiards immediately following the pool cue striking the ball near the bottom propelling the ball forward with what is called "backspin". The progression of its motion is quite interesting. You can see it in slow motion about 1:55 into the following video.  https://www.google.com/search?q=physics+of+a+pool+draw+shot&sxsrf=ALiCzsZ6Hes__iFNCTVC_dYhBsoPJImwLg%3A1670794431620&ei=v0yWY46_JaPk5NoPsLivkA4&ved=0ahUKEwjOmtukwvL7AhUjMlkFHTDcC-IQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=physics+of+a+pool+draw+shot&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIHCAAQHhCiBDIFCAAQogQyBwgAEB4QogQyBQgAEKIEMgcIABAeEKIEOggIABCGAxCwAzoHCCMQsAIQJ0oECEEYAUoECEYYAFDACFi2D2D-FmgBcAB4AIABSYgBxQKSAQE1mAEAoAEByAECwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#kpvalbx=_MlyXY4fAF4rNytMP4u2UsAw_33

Hope this helps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the video you provided - it was very helpful. But I am still confused, because in Fig. 2 you're splitting f_k such that the acceleration of COM is non-zero, but what I've learned in school is that tangential forces (90° to the radius) only rotate a body (which makes sense to me).

In the first and second phase (backspin and stun), does the center of mass change speed (while neglecting aerodynamic drag) or is it constant? It looks like it only changes speed of COM at the third phase - if so, how do I find that particular angular velocity?

Comment: the friction force doesn’t only  rotate the body. What are the sum of the forces in the horizontal direction?

Comment: Look carefully at the video. The speed is less at the end than the beginning.

Comment: The angular velocity at the end (pure roll) equals the velocity of the COM divided by the radius

Answer (score 1):

The frictional force causes a positive linear acceleration for the centre of mass, but it decreases the angular acceleration. There is no requirement that the friction should decrease linear velocity. When you're writing force equations, you write $ \vec f_{k} = M_{c} \cdot \vec a_{c}$ where $ M_{c} $ and $ a_{c} $ are the mass and acceleration of the centre of mass. This acceleration, depending on the rotation of the ball/sphere, can/will be in the same direction of the centre of mass.

When writing torque equations, assume clockwise is positive and friction is acting towards the right:

$ \vec T_{net} = \vec R \times \vec f =I \vec \alpha $

This $ \vec \alpha $ turns out to be along the counter clockwise direction, which, if the body was initially doing rotation in the clockwise direction, would cause an angular retardation.

If there is slipping, and there is angular retardation, then the sphere is going to, at some point, attain rolling condition, where it won't slip any longer, and would just roll. In that case, the velocity of the centre of mass would be $v_{com}= R\omega$ ( on a flat surface, the acceleration will be 0)

Edit: do note, I am assuming that the sphere is moving towards the right, with a clockwise rotation

Edit 2: for clarity, I'm assuming that $ | R \omega |› | v_{com} | $
The reason is: a ball spinning, and slipping has 2 motions which are working together: rotation about the centre of mass, translation of the centre of mass. If we were to consider translation of the ball alone, ignoring the rotation effects, the velocity of the point of contact of the ball with the floor will be the same as the velocity of the centre of mass. Now, let's consider the rotation motion alone, no translation. Here, the ball is rotating with $ \omega $ , with respect to COM. Therefore, the velocity of the point of contact would be $R\omega$ in the leftward direction. If you add these two motions, your point of contact would have a velocity towards the right, of magnitude $ | v_{com} - R\omega | $, depending on whether $ R\omega $ or $ v_{com} $ is higher in value, the direction of velocity of the point of contact changes, and hence the direction of kinetic friction will also change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand it correctly, then at higher angular velocities friction would only change the angular velocity. At some point, when the angular velocity would be low enough, the friction would become static and would accelerate the ball. After this acceleration, the ball would roll with 0 acceleration. But I don't know at what angular velocity this happens.

Comment: "The frictional force causes a positive linear acceleration for the centre of mass, but it decreases the angular acceleration". It sounds like you are referring to the static friction force acting forward on the ball if a torque applied at the axis of rotation, instead of the kinetic (sliding) friction force which always acts in opposition to the motion of the ball.

Comment: @Henry05 Just for clarification, are you talking about a ball that is only subjected to the kinetic friction force?

Comment: If the ball stops slipping, then the friction becomes static (relative to the surface of the ball) - is that when the center of mass starts to change its velocity? (that would make sense to me) If so, how do I find the angular acceleration at which it stops slipping?

Comment: @Henry05 if there are no external forces acting on the ball, when it stops slipping all friction ends and the angular and  linear acceleration is zero and you have $v_{com}= R\omega$

Comment: Please explain to me how kinetic friction increases linear acceleration of the COM, and decreases  angular acceleration, instead of it being the other way around.

Comment: Also, please explain to me how, when slipping stops, the ball will still undergo angular and linear acceleration? When slipping stops, the kinetic friction force stops. And unless there is another external force acting on the ball, there will also be no static friction and the ball will continue to roll with constant linear and angular speed due to its inertia.

Comment: @bobD, I have edited the answer with some more points, answering your question. I'm assuming the $R\omega$ is greater than $ v_{com} $ which means the point of contact is slipping backward, and hence friction acts forward. If indeed the initial $ v_{com} $ is greater than $ R\omega$, then the slipping will happen towards the right, and hence friction will act backward (left).

Comment: Regardless of whether initially $v_{com} > R\omega$ or $v_{com} <R\omega$ once slipping stops there is pure rolling with zero angular and linear acceleration. . You’re saying when slipping stops $a_{com}=R\alpha$.

Comment: @bobD, you are right, that was wrong. I should've written $ v_{com} = R \omega $ instead. The case I wrote might be only true for incline plane rolling, though. I will edit my answer